# End of File occurs when reading char 0x1A

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to read a file with around 1000 characters in it. The file reading terminates when an `0x1A` character is encountered. I want that:

1. `0x1A` should not terminate the reading.
2. `0x1A` should be stored like a normal character.

Can I use an alternate method of reading the file, maybe?

```
int main(void)
{
    int x=0,ch = ' ', file_name[25], arr[1000];
    FILE *fp;

    printf("Enter the name of file you wish to see\n");
    gets(file_name);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // read mode

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name); getchar();

    int y= 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d) %x \n",y, ch);
        arr[y++] = ch;
        printf(" %x \n", arr[(y- 1)]);
    }

    printf("Press to see the data off array..."); getchar();
    for (int x = 0; x < y; x++)
    {
        printf("%d ", (x + 1));
        printf(". %x \n", arr[x]);
    }
    getchar();
    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Where is `payload` declared in your program?

Comment: You should add the operating system you are using. Probably Windows.

Answer (score 4):

You opened the file as txt mode,

```
fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); // txt mode
```

Please try binary mode to read `0x1A`,like

```
fp = fopen(file_name, "rb"); // binary mode
```

Comment: On some operating systems, this distinction is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fgetc()`  you can use `fgets` .

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d) %x \n",y, ch);
        payload[y++] = ch;
        printf(" %x \n", arr[(y- 1)]);
    }
```

you can simply write this using `fgets()`-

```
#define MAX 1024
                  //open file in "r" mode 
char arr[MAX];
while(fgets(arr,MAX,fp))
 {
    printf("%s",arr);
 }
```

Content in you file is stored in array `arr`.
While using `fgets` you don't have to worry about `EOF` as `fgets` itself return as it encounters `EOF`.

Comment: The issue is that if there is character 0x1A (the substitute character) fgets() returns premature EOF.  It cannot read past this point of the file.