# fstream stops to read at substitute control character

Tags: c++, encryption, fstream

I'm writing a simple encryption program in C++ to encrypt a text-based file.
It's using a simple XOR cipher algorithm, but this produces ASCII control characters in the output file. When I try to read from the newly encrypted file with `std::ifstream`, it stumbles upon character `#26`, it stops and becomes unable to read the rest of the file.

Example if I try to encrypt this text:

```
This is just a simple sample
text with two rows and one sentence.
```

It turns it to this

```
/[[[[[
[[[ [[[U
```

When I try to read that file in my program, it can't read past the character at position 15, so I get a half encrypted file.

How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void Encrypt(char encryptionKey, std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename);
    std::ofstream outputFile(filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of("\\")) + "\\Encrypted" + filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("\\") + 1), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    std::string sourceLine;
    std::string outputLine;
    long numLines = 0;
    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opening file: " + filename + " for encryption" << std::endl;
        while (sourceFile.good()) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            sourceLine = ""; //Clearing the line for each new line
            outputLine = ""; //Clearing the line for each new line

            std::getline(sourceFile, sourceLine);
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceLine.length(); i++) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {

                char focusByte = sourceLine[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                outputLine.push_back(focusByte);
                //std::cout << sourceLine << std::flush;

            }
            numLines++;
            outputFile << outputLine << std::endl;
        }
    }
    sourceFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}

void Decrypt(unsigned int encryptionKey, std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename);
    std::ofstream outputFile(filename.substr(0, filename.find_last_of("\\")) + "\\Decrypted" + filename.substr(filename.find_last_of("\\") + 1), std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    std::string sourceLine;
    std::string outputLine;
    long numLines = 0;
    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opening file: " + filename + " for decryption" << std::endl;
        while (sourceFile.good()) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            if (sourceFile.fail() == true)
                std::cout << "eof" << std::endl;
            sourceLine = ""; //Clearing the line for each new line
            outputLine = ""; //Clearing the line for each new line

            std::getline(sourceFile, sourceLine);
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceLine.length(); i++) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {
                char focusByte = sourceLine[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                outputLine.push_back(focusByte);

            }
            numLines++;
            outputFile << outputLine << std::endl;
        }
    }
    sourceFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
}


int main(int argument_count,
    char * argument_list[])
{
    system("color a");
    std::string filename;
    if (argument_count < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "You didn't supply a filename" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        filename = argument_list[1];
        std::cout << "Target file: " << filename << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Press e to encrypt the selected file, Press d to decrypt the file > " << std::flush;
        char choice;
        while (true)
        {
            std::cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'e')
            {
                Encrypt(123, filename);
                break;
            }
            else if (choice == 'd')
            {
                Decrypt(123, filename);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "please choose option e or d for encryption respectivly decryption" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }


    std::cout << "\nPaused, press Enter to continue > " << std::flush;
    system("Pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You **must** open binary files as [binary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode). The default is text. This is not what you want.

Answer (score 4):

In `Decrypt()`, after the first call to `std::getline()`, `sourceFile.good()` is false and `sourceFile.fail()` is true, which is why you stop reading subsequent lines from the encrypted file.

The reason is because the encrypted file has an encoded `0x1A` byte in it, and depending on your platform and STL implementation, that character likely gets interpreted as an EOF condition, thus enabling the `std::ifstream`'s `eofbit` state, terminating further reading.

In my compiler's STL implementation on Windows, when `std::ifstream` reads from a file, it ultimately calls a function named `_Fgetc()`:

```
template<> inline bool _Fgetc(char& _Byte, _Filet *_File)
    {   // get a char element from a C stream
    int _Meta;
    if ((_Meta = fgetc(_File)) == EOF) // <-- here
        return (false);
    else
        {   // got one, convert to char
        _Byte = (char)_Meta;
        return (true);
        }
    }
```

When it tries to read an `0x1A` character, `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, and when `_Fgetc()` returns false, `std::getline()` sets the `eofbit` on the `std::ifstream` and exits.

Check your compiler's STL for similar behavior.

This behavior is because you are [opening the encrypted file in text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315443/).  You need to open the encrypted file in `binary` mode instead:

```
std::ifstream sourceFile(..., std::ifstream::binary);
```

Also, you should enable `binary` mode on the encrypted file in `Encrypt()` as well:

```
std::ofstream outputFile(..., std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);
```

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

void Encrypt(char encryptionKey, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = filename.find_last_of("\\");
    std::string out_filename = filename.substr(0, pos+1) + "Encrypted" + filename.substr(pos + 1);

    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename.c_str());
    std::ofstream outputFile(out_filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opened file: " + filename + " for encryption" << std::endl;

        std::string line;
        long numLines = 0;

        while (std::getline(sourceFile, line)) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {
                char focusByte = line[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                line[i] = focusByte;
                //std::cout << line << std::flush;
            }

            outputFile << line << std::endl;
            ++numLines;
        }
    }
}

void Decrypt(char encryptionKey, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = filename.find_last_of("\\");
    std::string out_filename = filename.substr(0, pos+1) + "Decrypted" + filename.substr(pos + 1);

    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream outputFile(out_filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opened file: " + filename + " for decryption" << std::endl;

        std::string line;
        long numLines = 0;

        while (std::getline(sourceFile, line)) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {
                char focusByte = line[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                line[i] = focusByte;
            }

            outputFile << line << std::endl;
            ++numLines;
        }

        std::cout << "eof" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argument_count, char* argument_list[])
{
    std::system("color a");
    std::string filename;

    if (argument_count < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a file to process: " << std::flush;
        std::getline(std::cin, filename);
    }
    else
    {
        filename = argument_list[1];
    }

    if (filename.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "You didn't supply a filename" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Target file: " << filename << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press e to encrypt the file" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press d to decrypt the file" << std::endl;
    char choice;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "> " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 'e')
        {
            Encrypt(123, filename);
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'd')
        {
            Decrypt(123, filename);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "please choose option e or d for encryption or decryption, respectively" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Paused, press Enter to continue" << std::flush;
    std::system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

That being said, keep in mind that when using XOR, some of the encrypted characters might end up being `\r` (0x0D) or `\n` (0x0A), which will interfere with `std::getline()` when decrypting the file later on, producing a decrypted output that does not match the original text input.

Since you should be treating the encrypted file as binary, you should not be reading/writing the file as text at all.  Choose a different format for your encrypted output that does not rely on line-break semantics in text vs binary mode.

For example:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

void Encrypt(char encryptionKey, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = filename.find_last_of("\\");
    std::string out_filename = filename.substr(0, pos+1) + "Encrypted" + filename.substr(pos + 1);

    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename.c_str());
    std::ofstream outputFile(out_filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::binary | std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opened file: " + filename + " for encryption" << std::endl;

        std::string line;
        std::string::size_type lineLen;
        long numLines = 0;

        while (std::getline(sourceFile, line)) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            lineLen = line.length();

            for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < lineLen; ++i) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {
                char focusByte = line[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                line[i] = focusByte;
                //std::cout << line << std::flush;
            }

            outputFile.write((char*)&lineLen, sizeof(lineLen));
            outputFile.write(line.c_str(), lineLen);

            ++numLines;
        }
    }
}

void Decrypt(char encryptionKey, const std::string &filename)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = filename.find_last_of("\\");
    std::string out_filename = filename.substr(0, pos+1) + "Decrypted" + filename.substr(pos + 1);

    std::ifstream sourceFile(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::binary);
    std::ofstream outputFile(out_filename.c_str(), std::ofstream::trunc);

    if (sourceFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Opened file: " + filename + " for decryption" << std::endl;

        std::string line;
        std::string::size_type lineLen;
        long numLines = 0;

        while (sourceFile.read((char*)&lineLen, sizeof(lineLen))) // This iterates over the whole file, once for each line
        {
            line.resize(lineLen);
            if (!sourceFile.read(&line[0], lineLen))
                break;

            for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < lineLen; ++i) // Looping through all characters in each line
            {
                char focusByte = line[i] ^ encryptionKey;
                std::cout << " focusByte: " << focusByte << std::endl;
                line[i] = focusByte;
            }

            outputFile << line << std::endl;
            ++numLines;
        }

        std::cout << "eof" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argument_count, char* argument_list[])
{
    std::system("color a");
    std::string filename;

    if (argument_count < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a file to process: " << std::flush;
        std::getline(std::cin, filename);
    }
    else
    {
        filename = argument_list[1];
    }

    if (filename.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "You didn't supply a filename" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::cout << "Target file: " << filename << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press e to encrypt the file" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Press d to decrypt the file" << std::endl;
    char choice;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "> " << std::flush;
        std::cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 'e')
        {
            Encrypt(123, filename);
            break;
        }
        else if (choice == 'd')
        {
            Decrypt(123, filename);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "please choose option e or d for encryption or decryption, respectively" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Paused, press Enter to continue" << std::flush;
    std::system("pause");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ASCII value 26 is EOF on some operating systems.

You should probably treat your encrypted file as a byte stream rather than a text file for reading and writing.  That means either using `read()` and `write()` functions of the IOStream or at the very least opening the files in binary mode.

If you're just enciphering your text instead of encrypting, maybe choose a different cipher (eg. ROT13) that is closed on the set of printable ASCII or UTF-8 characters.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but can you clarify on "ASCII value 26 is EOF on some operating systems"? If you mean `EOF` constant, then it has to be not representable as `unsigned char`.

Comment: I mean there is at least one popular desktop operating system under which a byte with the value 0x1a is interpreted as end-of-file on a read operation when the file is opened as a 'text file'.  That will put the IOStream into an error state for subsequent read operations because it has detected a read-past-the-end-of-file condition.

Comment: And what OS is that?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Windows, for one (see my answer).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Huh, didn't know it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I compiled your code in Linux (minus all the Windows stuff)...

I get this when encrypting your sentence with your code:

```
/[[[[[
[[[ [[[U
```

It also decrypts back to the original sentence.  Without the goofy characters, it is the same as your output so your actual issue seems related to the encoding of the file and the program you are using to view the results.  Stephan is correct in saying you should be reading/writing bytes instead of text.  This can cause all sorts of issues with the characters you create.  For example, line feeds and carriage returns since you are using `getline()`.

Edit: Strange.  After editing this answer, all the odd characters disappeared.  Here is a screenshot:
[image: original output]